# How to pass a database value in a hyperlink using PHP + HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table in a database called Artists.
It contains two bands.
What I would like to do is to be able to click on the bands name using a hyper link, send that bands name to another php page to be processed

The hyper link syntax i have is throwing up errors:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM artists";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{                                  
   echo     
    "<a target='Main_Frame' href=Side_Menu_ContentPrint.php?Aname=<?php echo 
    $_POST['ArtistName'] ?>" . $row['ArtistName'] . "</a>";         
}
```

So I would like the above hyperlink to pass the bands name to Side_Menu_ContentPrint.php file so I can echo it to the screen (and use for more DB querying also). This file connects to the DB and contains:

```
$artist_Name = $_GET['Aname'];

echo "$artist_Name";
```

Just to show also, the following hyper link is working:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{    
   echo     
   "<a target='Main_Frame' href=Side_Menu_ContentPrint.php>" . $row['ArtistName'] . "  
   </a>";                                                           
}
```

and when click on it echos a test word to prove that it is working.
Any help would be great?

Regards, TW

Comment: You should use session variables instead of doing it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't put PHP code into echo and hope that it will run again.

Try this,

```
echo     
"<a target='Main_Frame' href='Side_Menu_ContentPrint.php?Aname=" . $row['ArtistName'] ."'>". $row['ArtistName'] . "</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch id of band, and place it into while loop to create dynamic functional links.
You could use band name instead of id, but it can lead to errors. Better to do with the primary key.

```
$id = $row['id'];
<a target='Main_Frame' href=Side_Menu_ContentPrint.php?id=$id>" . $row['ArtistName'] . "</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
echo "<a target='Main_Frame' href='Side_Menu_ContentPrint.php?Aname=".$_POST['ArtistName'].$row['ArtistName'] . "'</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `http_build_query` please see http://www.php.net/http_build_query

you can c onvert a PHP Array to a Query String… and Back Again , Please see below

```
 $myArray = array(  
        "car"=>array("ford", "vauxhall", "dodge"),  
        "animal"=>"elephant",  
        "language"=>"php"  
    );  

echo http_build_query($myArray);  

// Outputs: car[0]=ford&car[1]=vauxhall&car[2]=dodge&animal=elephant&language=php  


$queryString = "car=ford&animal=elephant&language=php";  

parse_str($queryString, $output);  

print_r($output); 

Array  
(  
    [car] => ford  
    [animal] => elephant  
    [language] => php  
)
```